# How to Destroy a moving object, such as a bullet

Tags: vb.net

I've been making a Space Invaders game for school and I have most of the mechanics done. My problem lies in the destruction of my bullet. When it hits an invader, the invader is killed and the bullet appears to be destroyed, but it continues and hits any other invaders in it's path. Ive been using this code...

```
 If bullet.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picInvader1.Bounds) And blnInvader1Alive = True And blnBulletExist = True Then
        Me.Controls.Remove(bullet)
        timBulletMovement.Enabled = False
        blnBulletExist = False
        blnInvader1Alive = False
        picInvader1.Visible = False
        picInvader1.SendToBack()
```

Comment: You have custom objects and custom logic that we know nothing about.  In the code you're showing, is there a specific statement which is failing in some way?  If so, what is it?  If not, why do you think this code is the cause of the problem?

Comment: It's hard to help based on this code, just make sure you check for blnBulletExist = True on all other part of the code.

Comment: Try dispong the control after removing it like this `bullet.Dispose()`